# Rudolf hat awarded for moving accept on old question

Tags: bug, status-completed, winterbash

So, according to it's description, to get the Rudolf hat you need to *"Accept an answer on a new question"*.

I have been awarded the hat for moving my accept on the question [How do I break a stack of objects?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26330/how-do-i-break-a-stack-of-objects/43406#43406) from an old obsolete answer, to a new up to date one.

This isn't a *new* question and does feel a little bit of a cheating way to get the hat.

Anyway, now you all know so either (a) it can be fixed or (b) everyone can get themselves a free hat.

Comment: Terrible injustice, of course... free hat, you say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed, so only people who asked questions during Hat Dash are eligible for the Rudolph Hat now. In the spirit of Christmas, the ~50 "undeserving" Rudolph Hat earners will get to keep their hats.

Comment: +1 for letting me keep my unearned hat.